# Developing a Kinect Speech Recognition app for a Surface table

Tags: wpf, kinect, speech, windows-rt

I'm currently developing a Kinect Speech Recognition application. The target platform will be a Surface tablet although the model hasn't been decided.

The application itself will allow interaction with children, with several basic game scenarios. My issue right now is that the demo's I've been using to test Kinect Speech Recognition capabilities were developing using WPF. It is to my understanding that WPF application cannot run on Surface and Surface 2 models as they both use Windows RT, leaving only the (expensive) Surface Pro 2 model running Windows 8 the only option.

With all this being said, is it possible to develop this kind of application (Kinect ASR) to run in a Windows RT environment? (I'm asking this due to the fact that every Kinect ASR apps I've seen so far are developed using WPF) 
If so, what are its limitations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple and clear answer, the whole Kinect development kit is not available for WinRT.

See also http://www.kinectingforwindows.com/2013/02/12/how-about-kinect-winrt/